# Error while exporting through Content Porter 2013 SP1 | Root element is missing

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013, content-porter

While exporting content through Content Porter, I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
[Error] Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportExportException: 
Application data with application id 'ugc:ComponentAndPage' of the item 
'/webdav/000%20Root/Building%20Blocks/demo/myImage.jpg' cannot be parsed. ---> 
System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
```

This Image component is created using "Default Multimedia Schema", there are other components of same schema which are getting exported in the package.

[image]

Environment: Windows Server 2008 R2, Tridion 2013 SP1, Content Porter logged in with Administrator account (same windows login account)

Is there any way, where this component can be corrected (without creating a similar new component and deleting the old)? info: Schema has been verified - it is fine.

Comment: Schema is fine you said as it is verified; is the component has also been verified? Can you open the component, Save & Close it successfully and then retry import/export

Comment: It seems issue with its component related to this multimedia component, see the error "ugc:ComponentandPage", Its looks like related to UserGeneratedContent. it could be issue with installation of ugc on destination machine.

Comment: Can you read applicationData for item "/webdav/000%20Root/Building%20Blocks/demo/myImage.jpg" with applicationId "ugc:ComponentAndPage"?
During exporting of the appdata, for ugc items it must be converted to XmlDocument...In your case it can not be parsed.

Comment: @Pankaj: yes.. component has also been verified, all components of that schema have been checked.. but this issue is there with only a few components (total 3)...

Syav4eg : How to read applicationData for any item??

Comment: CoreService.ReadApplicationData.
Also just for analyzing - try to export another item with ugcAppdata (can get item id from APP_DATA database table)

Comment: I have removed all old versions of these components (removing old items of this folder).. but no luck.. :(

Comment: Also modified the image by uploading a different small image. But still getting the same error.. Error screenshot attached in question..

Comment: a bit drastic but maybe backup the CM DB and then try to delete the AppData ugc:ComponentAndPage for these failing items.

Comment: @Raj the destination CMS might have UGC issues but this looks like a problem with Export. Saving a new version of an item would just copy the AppData "as is" into a new version. I think Philippe's approach would work, but instead of deleting the AppData, try to compare a "working" item with a UGC comment. Help from Support might be needed--as a supported module, UGC's AppData *should* work with Content Porter.

Comment: These 3 components which are failing have blank (0x) DATA_CONTENT under APP_DATA Table..

Even after purging all previous versions of components in this folder, APP_DATA contains all versions.. why so??

Comment: Thanks @PhilippeConil, deleting the AppData ugc:ComponentAndPage for these failing components worked..

Also, no new entry is created for AppData after saving the component again and again...

Can someone please explain the significance of this AppData Table...?? Thanks.

Comment: AppData is additional system data about an item in Tridion. It is data that is not needed to be seen by Tridion users, but rather leveraged programmatically. Tridion uses it itself to associate UGC comments and ratings to an item for instance, but for other things too. Developers can Read/Write AppData for customization purposes like UI extensions. see http://bit.ly/1lNIBCe and http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/get-all-applicationdata-with-given-id.html

Comment: Do I need to delete these blank App_data rows everytime I do an export?? Coz, I am getting errors for other components now. It will become a headache, since we need to do a daily backup - using ContentPorter export.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem today. In my case, I was selecting the application data category "User Generated Content." or as referenced in the error, ugcComponentAndPage. I did not need to select this category for my export. So, I went through the content porter export steps again, this time not selecting user Generated Content and my export completed without errors.
[image]